# Why copy constructor of std::chrono::duration is not constexpr?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, constexpr, duration

All constructors except the copy constructor of [std::chrono::duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration) are defined as constexpr. Why the copy constructor can't be defined as constexpr as well?

Answer (score 3):

Whether it can be `constexpr` or not depends on some internal details. From the language standard:

> The defaulted copy constructor of duration shall be a constexpr function if and only if the required initialization of the member rep_ for copy and move, respectively, would satisfy the requirements for a constexpr function.

So it will be `constexpr` if the internal representation of the class will allow it.